# Pthreads & Multicore compiler

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, linux-kernel, pthreads, embedded-linux

I'm working with the support SMP kernel:  Snapgear 2.6.21. 
I have created 4 threads in my c application, and I am trying to set thread 1 to run on CPU1, thread2 on CPU 2, etc.
However, the compiler sparc-linux-gcc does not recognize these functions:

```
CPU_SET (int cpu, cpu_set_t * set);
CPU_ZERO (cpu_set_t * set);
```

and this type: cpu_set_t
It always gives me these errors:

```
implicit declaration of function 'CPU_ZERO'
implicit declaration of function 'CPU_SET'
'cpu_set_t' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Here is my code to bind active thread to processor 0:

```
cpu_set_t mask;
CPU_ZERO (& mask);
CPU_SET (0, & mask) // bind processor 0
sched_setaffinity (0, sizeof(mask), & mask);
```

I have included and defined at the top :

```
**define _GNU_SOURCE
include <sched.h>**
```

But I always get the same errors. can you help me please?

Comment: Edit your question by formatting it better. Use four spaces between each line of code (with an empty line before and after the code chunk). And you should test the return value of `sched_setaffinity`

Comment: You might show much more source code and your compilation command. Feel free to edit your question.

Comment: Is using `taskset` or `numactl` a possible alternative for you, @Mariem?

Comment: Have you made sure #define _GNU_SOURCE is included at the very top, before including any headers, as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794338/implicit-declaration-of-function-sched-setaffinity ? 
I had the same problem and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

You should read [sched_setaffinity(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) carefully and test its result (and display `errno` on failure, e.g. with `perror`).

Actually, I believe you should use [pthread_setaffinity_np(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html) instead (and of course test its failure, etc...)

Even more, I believe that you should not bother to *explicitly* set the affinity. Recent Linux kernels are often quite good at dispatching running threads on different CPUs.

So simply use pthreads and don't bother about affinity, unless you see actual issues when benchmarking.

BTW, passing the `-H` flag to your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (cross-)compiler could be helpful. It shows you the included files. Perhaps also look into the preprocessed form obtained with `gcc -C -E` ; it looks like some header files are missing or not found (maybe some missing `-I` *include-directory* at compilation time, or some missing headers on your development system)

BTW, your [kernel](http://kernel.org/) version looks ancient. Can't you upgrade your kernel to something newer (3.15.x or some 3.y)?

Comment: Linux' scheduling can be quite bad too - it's possible it groups threads on the same core if their load is uneven and Linux determines they're mostly not doing anything.

Comment: This is not answer.  It's bad form to respond with basically, read the manual and you shouldn't do that.  If people post questions on stackoverflow they may very well have good reasons for doing what they ask.  If you want to recommend a different course of action rather than answer the question then leave a comment instead.

Comment: It is an answer, and I am giving additional information (notably the hint to avoid caring about affinity without good reason) that man page does not give a lot